# Interact over object of arrays React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an object like this one:

```
[
    {
        "periodname": "Test",
        "periodtime": ""
    },
    {
        "periodname": "",
        "periodtime": ""
    }
]
```

And I want to render a **Col** for each array inside of it. My React code:

```
function renderMyPage(props) {

const { myObject } = props

const renderMyPage = () => {
     return [myObject].map((c,i) => {
        return(
            <Col>
              My data here  
            </Col>
          )
       })
    }
}
```

But I always get only one result, even if I have two or more arrays inside my object.

If I interact again with **map** or **foreach** I get the same object.
If I use the map function without using "[]" on the object I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

What I'm doing wrong to get only one result? Tried a lot of other questions around StackOverflow questions but I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick solution try

```
const renderMyPage = () => {
     return myObject?.map((c,i) => {
        return(
            <Col>
              My data here  
            </Col>
          )
       })
    }
}
```

or

```
const renderMyPage = () => {
     if (!myObject) return null;
    
     return myObject.map((c,i) => {
        return(
            <Col>
              My data here  
            </Col>
          )
       })
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to tell the TypeScript compiler that you know for sure `myObject` is defined, you can use `return myObject!.map(...`